# How can I reuse a derived value in a query

Tags: mysql

There must be a more efficient way to do this, but I am not familiar with mySQL enough yet to know what terms to research. I've been looking at the AS keyword.

Below is my working query. See how I've had to derive the duration (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(           FinishTime,StartTime)) multiple times. Is it possible to derive it once and reuse it within this query?

```
table: AuraUsers
fields: ID, StartTime, FinishTime, Completed


SELECT 
    TIME_TO_SEC(
        TIMEDIFF(
            FinishTime,
            StartTime
        )
    ) 
    AS json 
    FROM AuraUsers 
    WHERE (
        StartTime IS NOT NULL 
        AND 
        FinishTime IS NOT NULL 
        AND 
        Completed=7 
        AND 
        TIME_TO_SEC(
            TIMEDIFF(
                FinishTime,
                StartTime
            )
        ) > 0 
        AND 
        TIME_TO_SEC(
            TIMEDIFF(
                FinishTime,
                StartTime
            )
        ) < 90275
    ) 
    ORDER BY TIME_TO_SEC(
        TIMEDIFF(
            FinishTime,
            StartTime
        )
    ) DESC 
    LIMIT 0,535;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `HAVING` clause,but it is not reusing actually it will evaluate the whole expression each time you use the alias in query

```
SELECT 
    TIME_TO_SEC(
        TIMEDIFF(
            FinishTime,
            StartTime
        )
    ) 
    AS json 
    FROM AuraUsers 
    HAVING (
        StartTime IS NOT NULL 
        AND 
        FinishTime IS NOT NULL 
        AND Completed=7 
        AND json > 0 
        AND json < 90275
    ) 
    ORDER BY json DESC 
    LIMIT 0,535;
```